# I dont want to register my app in facebook ,i need post comments on user facebook wall page

Tags: android

I don't want to register my app in Facebook, I need to post comments on the users Facebook wall page. How to implement this? If I press button it should show users Facebook wall page to publish comments about app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, its not possible to directly post on someone's wall, you have to register your app with FB first, then user have to allow permissions to post on their wall.

Comment: Using FB sdk for android, its official by FB itself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you either register your app, or you don't post comments. You choose.

The only option I can think of that does not require registration is to have a webview that will go to the user's facebook url, i.e. `<a href='http://www.facebook.com/USERNAME/'/>`

Comment: if i register app in facebook it is reflecting comments in my app .i dont want to show user comments in my app storedin facebook,i like to reflect in user facebook account so that every one can view about my app.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to register the application on facebook by providing them the Hash key of your application. Its used to make sure the facebook interacts with your application.

Comment: if i register app in facebook it is reflecting comments in my app .i dont want to show user comments in my app storedin facebook,i like to reflect in user facebook account so that every one can view about my app.

Comment: help me. how to do this? using hashkey

Comment: Well, as i mentioned in my answer its not possible to communicate with facebook without getting your application registered at developer.facebook.com. here is a link which will help you getting your application register.  [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android)